# Login using email address in roundcube in one server

Tags: postfix, dovecot, roundcube

How to config roundcube setting so that I can login using my full email address instead of username.

I can login in roundcube using `john`, but I cant login successfully with `john@mydomain.com`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't configure this in roundcube, you configure this in the IMAP server, dovecot in your case.

However, the exact configuration depends on what user-backend you have configured and on what distribution you are using on your server (the configuration files differ between distributions).

Answer (score -1):

I can't tell you exactly what happens from the top of my head, but one source that has helped me very much in setting up an e-mail server is: https://workaround.org/ispmail/stretch/setting-up-dovecot

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.